# Ruby on Rails: Cannot check the checkbox in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am testing my code in Ruby on Rails but cannot place checkmark in the checkbox, and no idea why. I am using RSpec.

In the test code I set to place a checkmark in the checkbox that have association with Task model, but got errors.

・I confirmed 'checkbox' appears in the error page screenshot.
・I get 'ElementNotFound' message and cannot place a checkmark （Error details below）

Following are my code related to this problem.

Anyone can help? Thank you.

```
#app/views/tasks/_form.html.erb

<% Label.all.each do |label| %>
   <%= form.check_box :label_ids, { multiple: true, checked: label[:checked], disabled: label[:disabled], include_hidden: false }, label[:id] %>
   <%= label.name %>
<% end %>
```

```
#spec/system/task_spec.rb 

describe 'Checking Labels' do
  before do
    FactoryBot.create(:label)
  end
  context 'When I select Label' do
    it 'Selected label appears in the show page' do
      visit new_task_path
      fill_in 'task_task_name', with: 'TEST'
　　　 check "label1"
      click_on 'Go'
      click_on 'Detail'
      expect(page).to have_content "label1"
    end
  end
end
```

```
#factoryBot

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :label do
    name { "label1" }
  end
end
```

```
#Error message

Failure/Error: check "label1"
     
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find checkbox "label1" that is not disabled
```

Comment: I found with Capybara that using the id for the checkbox (if you can) is the most successful at this. `check "#label1"`

Comment: @sam That won't work - check can take the id but it doesn't take a CSS selector

Comment: @ThomasWalpole, you're right. But you can do `find("#label1").check`.

Comment: @sam  Yes you could but then you could also just do `check ‘label1’` which would match on the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing the `erb` isn't very useful because it doesn't actually fully define what HTML is produced without more info, so in the future please always provide the actual HTML produced in your test.

The reason this isn't working for you is because you're trying to click based on the label name, but that name isn't associated with the checkbox in any way. If you look at the actual HTML of the page you'll see there's no label element with a `for` attribute linking it to your checkbox, and clicking on the text doesn't toggle the checkbox as it should.

You probably want to be looking at the `collection_check_boxes` method, or manually using the `label` method on the form builder with something like

```
<% Label.all.each do |label| %>
   <%= form.check_box :label_ids, { multiple: true, checked: label[:checked], disabled: label[:disabled], include_hidden: false }, label[:id] %>
   <%= form.label :label_ids, label.name, value: label[:id] %>
<% end %>

which should create a label element associated with the check box and allow you to find the element by the label text, so `check 'label1'` will work.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved the problem with your advice! collection_check_boxes method is new to me, so I would study it to use it in the future.

Comment: @HiroKoba you’re welcome, please don’t forget to accept the answer so the question gets marked as answered

Comment: @ Thomas Walpole I got it, thank you! In the future I show HTML code as well.